# Flex box and percentage width hiding image

Tags: css, flexbox

Consider the following html

```
<menu class="main">
    <menuitem><img src="blah" class="foo"></menuitem>
</menu>
```

These elements are styled using flexbox

```
menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: stretch;
}

menuitem {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  align-items: center
}

.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto; //Align to the far right
}
```

This works as expected except that if the flex and width are percentages, then when I resize the screen, rather than staying on the right edge of the menu bar it simply begins to disappear. Is there a way to get the image to stay pushed to the right even as the screen is resized?

Please also note that I'm using chrome to test, but I have observed the same behavior on Safari. I'm using autoprefixer to take care of vendor prefixes.

**EDIT**

Here is a plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/bNUPWQnBDx9jM2E7zVnA?p=preview When you resize the viewport, the playstation logo moves off the screen instead of moving to fit the available space.

Comment: Can you post a demo of the full code?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is.  Could you reproduce it with the help of this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/9009qpg2/

Comment: See the edit. When you resize the view port, rather than squishing into the available space, it just moves off the screen.

Comment: Squishing works here though: http://run.plnkr.co/I3ZrBhOGlksbfcjM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `flex-direction:column` to your `menu`

and I would change:

```css
.foo { max-width:25% }
```

to

```css
.foo { max-width:100% }
```

so the image would fit naturally.

P.S. - I used a different image because your image is encoded.
here is a snippet:

```css
menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: blue;
  flex-direction:column;
}

menuitem {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  align-items: center
}

.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto; 
}
```

```html
<menu class="main">
    <menuitem><img height="200" src="http://i1303.photobucket.com/albums/ag160/TrekMD/RVG%20Images/PlayStationOneLogo_zps6b738565.png
" class="foo"></menuitem>
  </menu>
```

Comment: Specifically your tip about changing max-width to 100% fixed the issue for me. Thanks